# button visibility on bottom sheet behavior change

Tags: android, bottom-sheet

I have a button called share on bottomsheet ,now i want that button to be visible only if the state is expanded , in any other state button should not be visible. here is the code i have tried.

```
     if (mBottomSheetBehavior.getState() == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED) {share.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);}
    if(mBottomSheetBehavior.getState()==BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED){share.setVisibility(View.GONE);}
    if(mBottomSheetBehavior.getState()==BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_SETTLING){share.setVisibility(View.GONE);}
    if(mBottomSheetBehavior.getState()==BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_SETTLING){share.setVisibility(View.GONE);}
```

but when i drag bottomsheet for expand or collapse nothing happens , is there any correct way that i don't know

Comment: Yes there is a way https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```html
mBottomSheetBehavior.setBottomSheetCallback(new BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onStateChanged(View bottomSheet, int newState) {
        if (newState == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED) {
               share.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }else{
               share.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
 
    @Override
    public void onSlide(View bottomSheet, float slideOffset) {
    }
});
```

Comment: That's correct answer . I have used this method but i forgot , and I am new to android and stack overflow why are u downvoting me instead of helping